# What does explorer use to open a file?

Tags: c, winapi, shell, explorer

I am attempting to hook into whatever explorer calls when a file is opened (double-click, context menu open, etc.), however I can't figure out which function that is.

Originally, I thought it was ShellExecute, as that does the same thing as far as I can tell, but after hooking into it I learned that it's only used when a new explorer window is opened.

Any ideas which function I should be hooking?

Comment: Just to be sure, you also checked ShellExecuteEx? :) Otherwise, just CreateProcess comes to mind...

Comment: What is the purpose? Prevent users from opening certain files?

Comment: Writing a device driver to receive CreateProcess notification is the alternative.
The purpose is tracking whether a user has opened a file since our program modified it (obviously not 100% accurate, but this is the best way I can think of)

Comment: Also yes, I'm actually hooking ShellExecuteExW/A.

Comment: You should just look for change notifications on the file.

Comment: Why not hook/monitor access to that file rather than some other concept that is sometimes indirectly responsible for opening the file?

Comment: @Deanna Many applications (i.e. virus scanners, indexers) like to access files. Just monitoring access will give a ton of false positives

Comment: And monitoring ShellExecute will miss many true positives. At least you can filter out things like search indexers, virus checkers, thumbnailers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept these things, just register yourself as the default verb for shell items.  Here are some [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/shellintegration).

If you just want to know if someone has change some files you are interested in, you should register for change notifications via [FindFirstChangeNotification()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx) and related APIs.

Comment: We don't want to 'intercept,' we just want notification, assuming by intercept you meant completely overwrite the default behaviour. I considered doing this then passing it off to ShellExecute, but explorer obviously isn't doing that, so it made me a bit weary. We don't want to change the default behavior _at all_.

Comment: I'm not interested in files being changed. I'm interested in knowing when the user opens the file from explorer.

Answer (score 0):

There are the `ShellExecute` hooks, but now (after XP) are deprecated because everybody used them for the strangest purposes. Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/10/8938051.aspx) for some more detail, and at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775101%28VS.85%29.aspx) for some documentation.

Comment: Yes, we originally used these. We're trying to find a solution that works on Vista and up, thus a hook to whatever function is called, assuming someone knows which function that is and it's part of a dynamically linked library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [`AppInit_DLLs`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571) registry key should be good enough.

Make a simple DLL and call the [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(VS.85).aspx) in your DllMain function to get the full command line to the application being executed.

Comment: There is a simpler way to do this, which involves writing a device driver which can be subscribe for notification of the CreateProcess function. But a plain hook to whatever explorer calls would be our preferred method.

Answer (score -1):

Much simpler than writing a device driver ( but much less amusing ) is the MS research tool [detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). Have fun!

Comment: Detours is useless because I have no idea what function needs to be hooked (though I've concluded that the function isn't exposed from explorer), and would require us to buy a license just to add a very small feature. On top of that, I've already written code to hook functions.

Comment: Hmmm . . . well that's a tuffy . . . Here's another thought:
- Do detours as I suggested
- set break point in your code on intercepted file open system call
- Look at funcs in stack trace . . .
You'd then have the actual func to intercept . . . I've never done this . . don't know if it would work.  Maybe not!
TheEruditeTroglodyte